# Perl: Finding one value in one specific file in multiple directories

Tags: perl

I'm working on learning Perl since it's what the majority of our scripting is written in. I've dealt with Python and Java, each for a semester, while finishing my AS. I'm pretty fluent at deciphering a script if I know what its goal is but I've always had a hard time dealing with accessing other files/directories outside of my script's location.

I'm running into a problem with this part of the script. I'm trying to get it to open file "attrlist" and find a string in that file. That string will get sent to a text file but right now I just want to get to the point that the script is opening each file and finding the string.

When running the script I get a "gen_csh-10004-Script exited" error.

I'm running Perl 5.16.3.

```
foreach (@list){
    my $attrpath = "\/$_\/misc";
    # Verify that $attrpath is getting populated correctly.
    print "$attrpath\n";
    opendir(my $job,"\/genesis_data\/fw\/jobs$attrpath") or die "can't: $!";
    open (my $fh, '<', "attrlist") or die "couldn't open";
    my $panelsize = grep{!/^\va_panel_size = /}$fh;
}
```

Comment: Just a couple quick notes, unrelated to the actual problem:  You probably shouldn't use `-w`, and you don't need to escape all those forward-slashes.

Comment: So the input would be a directory, data\fw\jobs\, with numerous job folders (job1, job2, etc.) in it. That's being stored in @list. It just has a line by line list of all the job folders currently in the directory, so job1, job2, etc. on each new line. The output would go into each listed folder to a file in the job1\misc\ folder and pull a specified value out. This would go into the output text file and simply display "job1 attribute".

Comment: Are you saying that you are having trouble opening a file? You really should focus on that when describing your problem. You write way too much irrelevant information. What errors do you get? Also, `grep ... <$fh>` is how you use it.

Comment: You might also be interested in `glob`, which is a quicker way to read a directory, works like in the shell: `my @files = <$jobpath/*>`. `*` is wildcard, and it automatically hides files that begin with `.` (`<...>` is an alias for `glob "..."`)

Comment: "_I'm just getting a script exited error_"  -- what does that mean?  Exactly what "error" are you getting?  (What is printed to screen?)  You say that `$attrpath` seems correct so then that `print` is working ... what isn't?  It is unclear from the question what is failing

Comment: You do have a syntax error in the last shown line in the loop, `grep {...} $fh;` -- should be `<$fh>`.  That would result in a compilation error so the script wouldn't even run. Is that the problem?

Comment: @TLP, I do apologize. I'm sure my lack of Perl experience isn't helping a whole lot. I guess what I'm seeing is an error code, I just didn't realize it. The script is ending with "gen_csh-10004-Script exited". Up to creating my list of jobs works and I've verified that. When I get into trying to move into the directories for each item on the list is where I'm having issues. I know what I want to happen I'm just not exactly sure how to go about it.

Comment: Thanks for addressing comments with your edit!  But this still isn't quite right -- There is sitll that `$fh` what it should be `<$fh>`. The shown code wouldn't compile, so it wouldn't run at all.  That may be "just" a typo in posting but is all the rest correct then?   Can you show us the code you actually have?  Details matter.

Comment: I did not see this before `/^\va_panel_size = /`, but this might be wrong. `\v` is an escape sequence that means `\v = Match any vertical whitespace character.` So this would match `a_panel_size` after a whitespace character at the beginning of a line. I did not notice it before, since you have a lot of incorrect escapes like `\/`.

Comment: This would explain if `$panelsize` is empty. But you never print $panelsize anyway, so you would never notice. That `Exited` message is not an error. It looks like a user-made exit message, or possibly some wrapper. But none of the Perl code you show would give that message. So again, you need to explain how you are experiencing a problem.

Comment: What do you think `opendir` is doing for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to recursively find all files named 'attrlist', and check if they contain the string 'va_panel_size'. So I would write the following :

```
use 5.10.0; # because of 'say'
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use Path::Tiny;

my $target_name    = "attrlist";
my $string_to_find = "va_panel_size";

my @files_to_inspect = File::Find::Rule->name($target_name)->in('.');

foreach my $file (@files_to_inspect) {
  say "inspecting $file";
  my $content = path($file)->slurp;
  say $& while $content =~ /^.*?$string_to_find.*/gm;
}
```